# Is there a way to work with files without leaving any trace of them? No showing up in recent lists in editors for example

Tags: files, security

I need to work with some files without leaving any long term trace of their existence - within reason. I don't care particularly if they could be pulled off the drive with recovery software, although preferably they would not be able to be. Is there any way I can do this? On Windows I would work with them in Sandboxie and simply delete the sandbox after I've finished, but I cannot find a linux equivalent. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use the guest account.

Answer (score 1):

The guest account does just that. It's like sandbox in windows in terms of privacy, as it auto deletes everything after you log off. Another method is to use live CD.

Comment: The guest account sounds like a good solution for that, thanks. I'll do some more investigation and mark this as answer if it works.

Comment: And? Did this help you?